# Python calculation for moving average

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I have a dataset as below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Category': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'],
        'Date' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
       'Count': [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I was trying to calculate the average count of every 3 rows excluding the current row grouped by category and the date is from new to old, if there is not enough 3 rows to calculate, it will return 0.

The expected result should be as below.
For example: for Category A for Date 1, the average is calculated as average count of dates 2, 3 and 4 of Category A.

| Category | Date | Count | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| A | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| A | 3 | 3 | 3.333333333 |
| A | 4 | 4 | 2.666666666 |
| A | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| A | 6 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| B | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| B | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| B | 4 | 5 | 0 |
| B | 5 | 6 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| C | 2 | 2 | 4.333333333 |
| C | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| C | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| C | 5 | 6 | 0 |

I was trying to use below, which didn't get expected result

```
df['average'] = df.groupby(['Category'])['count'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, 1).mean())
```

Comment: The average in the 4th row (`2.666666667` in category A) should be 0, correct? Otherwise it looks inconsistent with B and C.

Comment: @Shaido it should be 2.66667, as if it has less than 3 rows to calculate, it will return 0.

Comment: Then, please explain how you get 2.666. If you only use 2 rows you will have (5+1)/2=3. Aslo why are there 3 zeros for the B and C categories?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) in combination with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) as follows:

```py
def reverse_roll(df):
    df['Count'] = df.sort_values('Date', ascending=False)['Count'].rolling(3, 3).mean().shift()
    df['Count'] = df['Count'].fillna(0.0)
    df = df.sort_values('Date', ascending=True)
    return df
    
df.groupby('Category').apply(reverse_roll)
```

Above, `rolling(3, 3)` is used to force the rolling window to always consider 3 rows and not less. The first 2 rows the result will therefore be NaN which is set to 0 with `fillna`. To not include the current row in the window, `shift` is used.

Result:

```
   Category  Date     Count
0         A     1  3.000000
1         A     2  4.000000
2         A     3  3.333333
3         A     4  0.000000
4         A     5  0.000000
5         A     6  0.000000
6         B     1  4.000000
7         B     2  5.000000
8         B     3  0.000000
9         B     4  0.000000
10        B     5  0.000000
11        C     1  3.000000
12        C     2  4.333333
13        C     3  0.000000
14        C     4  0.000000
15        C     5  0.000000
```